# Incomplete Type Error when defining traits of templated structure

Tags: c++, templates

I've got a struct that finds the traits of the typename of the input:

```
template< typename > struct cstr_traits;
template< > struct cstr_traits< const char* >
{
    typedef char cstr_trait;
};
template< > struct cstr_traits< const wchar_t* >
{
    typedef wchar_t cstr_trait;
};
```

When used, I get `Type 'cstr_traits<char const(&)[4]> is incomplete'`. Here is the usage:

```
cstr_traits< decltype( "Foo" ) >::cstr_trait
```

Any ideas? I already tried this:

```
template< > struct cstr_traits< const const ( & )[ ] >
```

Why is it not being deduced to use one of the specialized templates?

Comment: The type `const const ( & )[ ]` is incomplete, as it's missing the size (which can be a template parameter).

Comment: Thanks @Someprogrammerdude - post that as an answer so I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the type of a string literal is not "pointer to first character" but "array of N const characters". This should do the trick:

```
template <std::size_t N>
struct cstr_traits<const char (&)[N]>
{
    using cstr_trait = char;
};
```

Also, for the sake of completeness, you probably wanna not forget about `char16_t` and `char32_t` in whatever it is that you're trying to do…